# GCP Compute Engine API keep requesting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Checking the APIs & Services dashboard, it always shows the Compute Engine API requesting even when I disabled the Compute Engine API.

Why? And is it normal?

When I disabled the Compute Engine API, it is still requesting but having 100% error as picture(I enabled it on Sep22).

I am not using the Compute Engine now, should I disabled it?

[image]

There are nothing about Compute Engine on Logs Viewer, as I don even have VM instances.

I can only see there are many Traffic by API method since enabled.

It seem to come from "List requests", but I don know what is it and why it keep requesting?

[image]
...
[image]
...
[image]

Comment: Did you take a look at the cloud logging console to get more insight on this interaction?

Answer (score 1):

The Compute Engine service (compute.googleapis.com) is a dependency for many other Google Cloud services so it's possible this is why you continue to see traffic to this API.

You can enumerate your services:

```sh
gcloud services list \
--enabled \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

You can disable the Compute Engine service **but** be careful because this will break dependencies:

```sh
gcloud services disable compute.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

If you do this then rerun the `list` command, `compute.googleapis.com` should no longer be listed as enabled.